# cleartool find & describe -fmt, how to redirect output to a file?

Tags: redirect, clearcase, cleartool

On Windows I’m trying to run cleartool find command and get all versions in a branch that have a specific label, the output should include version and user name.

The command works great the problem is how to to redirect the output to a text file.

```
    cleartool find -avobs -branch brtype<BRANCH>) -version "lbtype(<LABEL>)" -exec "cleartool describe -fmt \"%Xn : %u\n\" \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\"
```

I have tried using >, >>, |, | tee combinations but nothing works

Any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap the command in a CMD shell, which can then be redirected:

```
cmd /C "cleartool find -avobs -branch (brtype<BRANCH>) -version "lbtype(<LABEL>)" -exec "cleartool describe -fmt \"%Xn : %u\n\" \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\""" > aText
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have thought about it by myself….

Comment: @Elad no problem: hopefully, it will help others.

Comment: In continuing to my old question
The command I’m using retrieve several ClearCase properties, one of them is the description\comment that may include empty lines,
in that case the .csv file I get is wrong since the empty line and any text that appears after it is written to a new line in the .csv file.
Any ideas how to solve it ?

Comment: @Epligam 3 years later... it looks like you might to do some post-processing of the cleartool command output. Namely put everything on one line, *before* puting it in a .cvs file.