# How do I list the description of a clearcase file?

Tags: command, clearcase, cleartool

I know that I can list all files I have on the "MyBranchName" with the following command:

`cleartool find . -cview -type f -branch 'brtype(MyBranchName)' -print`

But I need to know the description / (or comment if you want) of the files which you can set when you do checking-out or checking-in . Is there a way to do that too ?

I already searched for the internet after a solution, but couldn't find it. I start to think that it isn't even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`cleartool describe`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-clearcase/8.0.0?topic=ucm-describe) command should be involved here.

With Linux (or Windows Git bash shell), you might consider:

```bash
cleartool find . -cview -type f -branch 'brtype(MyBranchName)' -print | \
   xargs -I {} cleartool describe -fmt "%n: %c\n" {}
```

But using `cleatool find -exec` should be more efficient:

I [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31857913/6309):

```
cleartool find -avobs -branch (brtype<BRANCH>) -version "lbtype(<LABEL>)" -exec "cleartool describe -fmt \"%Xn : %u\n\" \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\""
```

In your case:

```
cleartool find -cview -branch 'brtype(MyBranchName)' -exec "cleartool describe -fmt \"%n : %c\n\" \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\"
```

Linux syntax:

```
cleartool find -cview -branch "brtype(MyBranchName)" -exec 'cleartool describe -fmt "%n : %c\n" "$CLEARCASE_XPN"'
```

Answer (score 1):

@VonC
The output of that command will be:
m:\myview\myvob\dir1\myfile.txt@@\main\branch {comment on BRANCH creation}

Use -version instead, and consider using -all. For example, though I didn't include -type f so you see more than one line of output and also see comments (most of my test checkins are -nc...):

```
cleartool find -all -version "brtype(p50-branch)" -exec 'cleartool desc -fmt "%n : %c\n" $CLEARCASE_XPN'
/view/ncaexported/vobs/bc-linuxtest/test1@@/main/p50-branch/0 : 
/view/ncaexported/vobs/bc-linuxtest/test1@@/main/p50-branch/1 : Added file element "testthis.txt".

/view/ncaexported/vobs/bc-linuxtest/test1/temp1.txt@@/main/p50-branch/0 : 
/view/ncaexported/vobs/bc-linuxtest/test1@@/main/p50-branch/1/testthis.txt@@/main/p50-branch/0 : 
/view/ncaexported/vobs/bc-linuxtest/test1@@/main/p50-branch/1/testthis.txt@@/main/p50-branch/1 :
```

Comment: @VonC because I needed to show output, this became too long for a comment...

Comment: Nice, that would work indeed. Thank you for the feedback, and happy new year.